# Is there a (co-)homology theory for smooth manifolds which identifies spaces up to isomorphism?

Tags: homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

All homology theories I'm aware of are defined up to homotopy.  Of course, for something to be eglegible for the name "homology theory", it has to satisfy the [Eilenberg-Steenrod Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms), of which the first is the homotopy invariance.

But if we dropped this requirement, could a (co-)homology theory which identifies real smooth manifolds up to isomorphism exist?

Comment: What do you mean by an “isomorphism” between smooth manifolds?

Comment: An isomorphism in the category of smooth manifolds, i.e. a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/84534/6751) are relevant.